# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta en 3 tablas, excluyendo los registros en una de ellas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 3 tablas y quiero hacer una `SELECT`. En las tres hay un campo llamado `usuario` lo que deseo hacer es traer todos los registros que sean iguales en la tabla uno y dos pero que no incluyan si esta en la tabla 3.
Seria algo asi:

```
(usuario.T1=usuario.T2)!=usuarioT3
```

No logro hacer que me arroge un resultado correcto espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que necesitas una mezcla entre `JOIN` y `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabla1 as T1
INNER JOIN Tabla2 as T2
   ON T1.usuario = T2.usuario
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Tabla3
                 WHERE usuario = T1.usuario);
```

O con un `INNER JOIN` y `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM Tabla1 as T1
INNER JOIN Tabla2 as T2
   ON T1.usuario = T2.usuario
LEFT JOIN Tabla3 as T3
   ON T1.usuario = T3.usuario
WHERE T3.usuario IS NULL;
```

Comment: Me parece que `NOT IN` es más performant que `NOT EXISTS`. [Ver aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/5587982)

Comment: @A.Cedano en SQL Server, `NOT EXISTS` y `NOT IN` tienen casi idéntico performance, si bien se recomienda `NOT EXISTS` en caso de haber valores `NULL`. En mysql, en cambio, el mejor performance se obtiene usando `LEFT JOIN` y `IS NULL`

Comment: En cuanto a rendimiento es mejor usar not exists o un left join?

Comment: @Criss Como digo, depende del motor de bases de datos. En mysql, generalmente `LEFT JOIN` entrega mejor rendimiento que `NOT EXISTS`. En SQL Server, es al revés

Answer (score -3):

amigo no te entiendo lo que me dices pero me imagino algo asi no tengo manejadores ahorita para probar ve a ver si esta idea te sirve..

(Select * from T1,t2 WHERE usuario.T1=usuario.T2 and usuario.T1,usuario.T2=!usuario.T3;)